# How to write a functional test script to run under cmake/ctest

Tags: cmake, ctest

Under cmake, the following commands in a `CMakeList.txt`

```
enable_testing()
add_test(<test_name> <test_command>)
```

suffice to create a test that can be executed through the shell command `ctest`.

Unfortunately, the cmake docs give not the least indication of what constitutes a valid test executable (`<test_command>`). Usually, test executables are generated using a framework like google-test. It's a bit involved, but there are good examples in the web that show how to make tests under google-test under cmake.

Now I want to extend my use of cmake/ctest to functional test scripts that need not to be compiled, and therefore cannot be run under google-test. Thence my question: what constitutes a valid hand-written test executable to be directly activated through `add_test`:

- Shall my test executable generate output? Shall it write to stdout or stderr?
- Shall my test executable return certain values to indicate success or failure?
- Or where in the cmake docs can I find the answer?

Comment: I have reported the lack of documentation at https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15798.

Comment: They responded quickly, the 3.5 docs will contain the answer: https://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=f19d6a2c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your executable should return zero if the test passes and nonzero if not. Outputs are ignored.
The documentation for `add_test` doesn't mention this.

Comment: Thanks. And what about the additional output one can obtain using `ctest -V`? Isn't that generated via stdout or stderr?

Comment: Yes, both stdout and stderr of the test are displayed with `ctest -V`. But it's only for human supervision or debugging. `ctest` itself ignores both stdout and stderr of the test.